# Angular 404 error when navigating in Vercel

Tags: angular, vercel

After I posted my project in Vercel, everything is fine when navigating through the pages, but if you reload the page not on the main "/" but on any other route, then there will be a 404 error.
I managed to find a solution on the internet by adding

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }.
```

However, now my paths always look like this /#/... (starts with #). To be honest, it's ugly and obviously inconvenient for users. Are there other ways to get rid of this error without resorting to HashLocationStrategy?

Using PathLocationStrategy error 404 remains relevant

Answer (score 1):

Vercel host SPA by invoking the build command and serve the bundled static file.

Build your angular locally and check for the directory of the `index.html` file. It is usually `<dist>/<ng project name>/<platform>`. For my case it is `dist/frontend/browser`.

Put that directory path in the Output Directory section under your Vercel Project Settings page. Please be noted that the change will not apply instantly, you must push something to the main branch of your git repo to trigger the Vercel build process.

[image: Vercel Project Settings - Build & Development Settings]